# Serilog LogContext.PushProperty not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

I'm initializing Serilog in Program.cs, reading the configuration from appsettings.json, adding middleware in Startup.cs -> Configure and Use Request Middleware. Some snippets:

**Starup Extension**

```
     public static void UseSerilogRequestMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder app)
     {
            app.UseMiddleware<RequestMiddleware>();
            app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
     }
```

**Create Logger**

```
       Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.UDPSink(configuration["Serilog:LogstashUrl"], int.Parse(configuration["Serilog:LogstashPort"]), new JsonFormatter())
                .CreateLogger();
```

**Middleware**

```
       public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            if (httpContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContext));

            try
            {
                using (LogContext.PushProperty("CorrelationId", httpContext.GetCorrelationId()))
                using (LogContext.PushProperty("UserName", httpContext.Request.Headers["UserName"]))
                using (LogContext.PushProperty("Path", httpContext.Request.Path))
                using (LogContext.PushProperty("QueryString", httpContext.Request.Query))
                {
                    await _next(httpContext).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
```

**appSettings**

```
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [ { "Name": "Console" } ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithExceptionDetails" ],
    "Filter": [
      {
        "Name": "ByExcluding",
        "Args": {
          "expression": "RequestPath like '/health%'"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "ByExcluding",
        "Args": {
          "expression": "RequestPath like '/swagger%'"
        }
      }
    ],
    "LogstashUrl": "logstash-teste-log",
    "LogstashPort": "5045"
  }
```

In the middleware I want to push some properties to the logs. When I configure Serilog as written above the properties are not visible in the logs

Comment: Try and remove the ConfigureAwait. Per [this](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1291) that's the only difference you have but that'd be weird since there's no sync context in aspnetcore (which btw means you can drop ConfigureAwait in general)... But it's the only difference between what you have and they have